# Regex to match multiline string start with x, ends with y and contains z but not x in the middle

Tags: regex, sublimetext, non-greedy

Better explain with an example.

This is text:

```
<li>hello 
THE WORDS
</li>

<li> cruel </li>

<li> world THE WORDS </li>
```

I want to find strings start with `<li>` and ends with `</li>` and contains `THE WORDS`. I am expecting to only match with `<li> hello THE WORDS </li>` and `<li> world THE WORDS </li>`.

What I tried: `(?s)<li>.*?(THE WORDS).*?</li>`

With this, second match is `<li> cruel </li> <li> world THE WORDS </li>`.

I am using Sublime Text.

Comment: I believe your "example" its making it more difficult than the actual data. Are the line breaks always at the positions as in your example? Can the strings "xx" and "yy" appear inside the lines?

Comment: @RoToRa I updated my example. Line breaks can be anywhere except "THE WORDS" and "<li></li>" parts, there is no "<li></li>" in text.

Comment: Ah, very, very, very different situation there. First remark has to be: You shouldn't be using regular expressions with HTML. Why do you have to use Sublime here? Considering this is HTML, JavaScript in a browser would be a better choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** For the new requirements, use this regex:

```
(?s)<li>(?:(?!</li>).)*?THE WORDS.*?</li>
```

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- `<li>` matches literal chars
- `(?:(?!</li>).)` asserts that what follows is not `</li` and matches one character
- The `*?` quantifier makes us lazily match up to....
- `THE WORDS`
- - The `*?` quantifier makes us lazily match up to....
- literal `</li>`

**Original Answer (different requirements):**

Use this simple regex (tested in Sublime):

```
x+[^xy]*z[^xy]*y+
```

See matches in the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/13).

**Explanation**

- `x+` matches one or more `x` chars
- `[^xy]*` matches any chars that are neither an `x` nor a `y`
- `z` matches the `z` we want (ensuring there is at least one)
- `[^xy]*` matches any chars that are neither an `x` nor a `y`
- `y+` matches one or more `y` chars

Comment: FYI: added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: great :) example n explanation

Comment: No problem, updated the answer: `(?s)<li>(?:(?!</li).)*?THE WORDS.*?</li>` Will add explanation, let me know if this works for you now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The below command would match only the `xx hello zz yy`, `xx world zz yy` strings and capture only `zz` from both the strings.

```
<li>(?:(?!<\/li>).)*(THE WORDS).*?<\/li>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bY3lL5/5)

Comment: My text is just example, there could be a lot more lines in one block. With this logic, i need to write every case as an or statement.

Comment: @m_poorUser how about this http://regex101.com/r/bY3lL5/4 ? It should work if have any number of lines in between